# Jackson change property names without copying POJO

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, jackson

Today I have found a problem which I need some advice from you.
I have a model from Frontend application which sends me some Json structure. It uses camelCase.
Then I need to send the same model to another service to trigger some functionality but there is a different Json name convention. It basically uses underscore notation instead of camel case but also there some other random differences so I would not say it is strict underscore.

And here's a problem. When I serialize Json from Frontend, is there a better way to remap those field names instead of creating duplicated model but with different JsonProperty annotation? I would like to avoid this solution because model contains around 15 classes so I would say it's big.

Another solution I was thinking about is JSONATA expression. What do you think?

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ADLayout {

    private String firstName;
    private LayoutHeader layoutHeader;
    private Long projectId;
    private List<Worksheet> worksheets;
}


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ADLayoutAnotherService {

    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @JsonProperty("layout_header")
    private LayoutHeader layoutHeader;

    @JsonProperty("project_id")
    private Long projectId;

    private List<Worksheet> worksheets;
}
```

**FRONT Model**

```
{
    "firstName": "test",
    "projectId": 5,
    "worksheets": [
        {
            "sheetUid": "201f1630-c97d-4fec-89b4-7b45b44bcebc",
            "sheetHeader": {
                "requestedData": "",
                "instructions": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Another service Model**

```
{
    "first_name": "test",
    "project_id": 5,
    "worksheets": [
        {
            "sheet_uid": "201f1630-c97d-4fec-89b4-7b45b44bcebc",
            "sheet_header": {
                "requested_data": "",
                "INSTRUCTIONS": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Important thing is that the model sent from Frontend is also stored in database and returned to frontend so @JsonAlias will not work here

Comment: You could have a look at implementing a custom `PropertyNamingStrategy` and register it with each of the object mappers used in both cases. You might have to enable `MapperFeature.ALLOW_EXPLICIT_PROPERTY_RENAMING` to allow Jackson to ignore the names provided in the annotations.

Comment: From a pure design point of view, they are two different models from two separate services and your service make a bridge between the two. You have no guarantee that one day one of the two services doesn't change the model (it may even change the service itself), so to me it makes perfectly sense to have them duplicated (they are two different DTOs), even if they happen to be very similar, practically the same, in this exact moment in time.

Comment: Thomas that's a good approach but this will work when there are all fields with the same naming convention but the problem is that some of the field are with underscore and some of them with camelCase. I was thinking about something like conditional @JsonProperty so depends on the parameter it will take proper name. Is that even possible?

Comment: As I know, all the annotations need a strict match with the structure. I wish there were such an annotation but I am afraid there is not. What about writing a mapper with MapStruct?

Comment: @mahmutoflaz that might work as well, I am just looking for best solution, because there are couple alternatives like Jsonata which I've mentioned where I will create expression to parse one model to another. I was just thinking if there is annotation based solution to avoid boiler plate code as much as possible